# Concat after checking condition in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to **CONCAT** a column in my pig if a certain condition is getting matched for that i am using below code but it is throwing error.

**CODE:**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pati1.hl7' USING PigStorage('|');
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($0 matches '.*OBR.*' or $0  matches '.*OBX.*');
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ($0=='OBR' ? CONCAT('OBR',CurrentTime(),$1) : ($0=='OBX' ? CONCAT('OBR',CurrentTime(),$1))) AS Uid; , $1 AS id, $5 AS result, $3 AS resultname;
Dump MSH_DATA;
```

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 13, column 122>  mismatched input ')' expecting COLON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source:[CONCAT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#CONCAT) :  *The data type of the two elements must be the same, either chararray or bytearray.*

First,You are trying to CONCAT fields of different datatype.Cast the fields to chararray.Second, your bincond syntax is incorrect.Since you have already filtered the records for values OBR and OBX,you need not check for `$0 == 'OBX'`.Third, when the value of `$0 == 'OBX'` you are again concatenating OBR with the current time which is same as the if part.Fourth, there is a ';' after Uid which is incorrect.

```
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ($0 == 'OBR' ? CONCAT('OBR',ToString(CurrentTime(), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssz'),(chararray)$1) : CONCAT('OBX',ToString(CurrentTime(), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssz'),(chararray)$1)) AS Uid, $1 AS id, $5 AS result, $3 AS resultname;
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation it helped a lot. I tried but i am getting below error `ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1052: 
<line 3, column 62> Cannot cast datetime to chararray`

Comment: @animal I've edited the answer.You will have to use ToString() to cast the datetime object.Use the right format for the datetime based on your requirement.